# SyntaxError in SkillsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, view, syntax, erb

I am getting a syntax error in my new.html.erb view.  My code is:

```
<h1>Add new skill</h1>
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
<p><label for="skill_title">Title</label>:
<%= text_field 'skill', 'title' %></p>
<%= collection_select :skill, :id, Skill.all, :id, :name %>
<%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

and my error is:

```
SyntaxError in SkillsController#new
app/views/skills/new.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

It is pointing to the very last line of my code.  Am I missing an end? I tried that and it did not work.  Thank you anyone who can spot my error and hopefully it is a simple one.

```
app/views/skills/new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting ')' ...r.append= form_tag (:action => 'create') do @output_buffer... ... ^ C:/HandCoOp/project/HandCoOp/app/views/skills/new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end ... form_tag (:action => 'create') do @output_buffer.safe_appe... ... ^ C:/HandCoOp/project/HandCoOp/app/views/skills/new.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error on the line above the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**form_tag**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)

To give you some clarity, `@user2675613` pointed out the following:

```
<%= form_tag ({action: "create"}) do %>
  <%= ... %>
<% end %>
```

According to the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag), you've got to use `do` at the end of the `form_tag` declaration, in order to give Ruby a `block` to work with.

If this does not work, I would look at how you're defining your route in the `form_tag` declaration. You're currently just using an `action`; I would use a `path helper` to define the route correctly

--

**Error**

The issue you have is as follows:

> unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

This basically means you're not calling `end` on a block, or have created a `code block` without defining the various arguments correctly. Using `do` basically defines to Ruby that you'll be using a block, and will therefore look for an `end` tag; which should be the fix you need

---

**Update**

In reference to your new error, it looks like it's asking you to include an `)` somewhere. Looking at [more Rails docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag), I would say this is what you'll have to do:

```
<%= form_tag ({action: "create"}) do %>
```

EG

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'create'}, {:id => 'anID'}) %>
```

Comment: Yes it did, thank you very much for helping me! You guys are the best<3

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your error it says:

```
SyntaxError in SkillsController#new
app/views/skills/new.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

This type of error comes when you are trying to close a loop that's not opened.

**Fix:**

```
<h1>Add new skill</h1>
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
<p><label for="skill_title">Title</label>:
<%= text_field 'skill', 'title' %></p>
<%= collection_select :skill, :id, Skill.all, :id, :name %>
<%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>  # this is the culprit of your error
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

But looking at your code it's a form so your end is supposed to be there but you forgot to open your loop:

```
<h1>Add new skill</h1>
<%= form_tag({action: "create"}) do %> #forgot this do to open your loop
  <p><label for="skill_title">Title</label>:
  <%= text_field 'skill', 'title' %></p>
  <%= collection_select :skill, :id, Skill.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>  # this is the culprit of your error
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

Comment: It's the `do` which will be the fix

Comment: @RichPeck yeah i saw it later that it's a form but then thought i should left the above block too so that he could understand the error better :)

Comment: and got this error that I will post above^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Written an answer to explain @user2675613's, and given my own recommendation!